# Trying to understand Android weird behaviour about BLE characteristics

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a server application that creates and expose a BLE service with two characteristics, with the following UUIDs:

```
mySvc: 00010000-0001-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
myCh1: 00010000-0002-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
myCh2: 00010000-0002-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

Here's what I get when connecting to my server with nRF connect:

[image]

Everything ok here.

Here's the code I use in my Android app:

```
private val gattCallback: BluetoothGattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {

    override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            for (s in gatt!!.services) {
                Log.d("[OnServicesDiscovered]", "found service: ${s.uuid}")
                for (c in s.characteristics) {
                    Log.d("[OnServicesDiscovered]", "found characteristic: ${c.uuid}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And here are the logs when discovering services:

```
D/[OnServicesDiscovered]: found service: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/[OnServicesDiscovered]: found characteristic: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/[OnServicesDiscovered]: found characteristic: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/[OnServicesDiscovered]: found service: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/[OnServicesDiscovered]: found characteristic: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/[OnServicesDiscovered]: found characteristic: 00002b29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/[OnServicesDiscovered]: found characteristic: 00002b2a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/[OnServicesDiscovered]: found characteristic: 00002b3a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/[OnServicesDiscovered]: found service: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/[OnServicesDiscovered]: found characteristic: 00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

I don't find my services / characteristics, but it appears that the two last UUIDs of the logs are respectively mySvc and myCh1 (I'm able to read on them, and they behave as expected).

Here are my questions:

1. Why does my service & characteristic have different UUIDs than the one nRF connect find?
2. Why do I only find the first characteristic, and not the second one?

Comment: Poaching in the UUID area of the Bluetooth SIG is not a very smart move. I think you are looking at a different Bluetooth device with your app than with the NRF app.

Comment: ftr "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" is the official  "Device Information" service, but most likely not the service your device will expose ...

Comment: i tried changing the UUID with random ones, I’m able to connect to my server (I connect with the MAC address) and I can read / write on my first characteristic, but still with the wrong UUID)

Comment: did you discover the surrounding device before you try to connect? If not, do so.

Comment: Yes I did it each time

Comment: You need to give us more information. Which hardware do you use as the GATT server? Have you compared the Infos of the server between NRF and your own application, for example the Name of the server?

Comment: The server is a go application, using the go-ble pkg, and running on a thinkpad laptop, the name is the same on the server / on the nRF app / on the android app, and is the one I choosed

Comment: I changed again all UUIDs because of your advice (didn't figured I took UUIDs from Bluetooth SIG range). It didn't worked at first, but deleting the phones Bluetooth cache did the trick. I now have my declared UUIDs for both my service and my characteristics